# Nested json response from 3 one to many tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, optimization, json, query-performance

I am designing data model in following way:

> Table 1:
>           id: number
>          somedata: String
>          somedata: String
>
> Table 2:
>          id: number
>          Table1_id: number
>          somedata: String
>          somedata: String
>
> Table 3:
>         id: number
>         Table2_id: number
>         somedata: String

1st table is joined to 2nd table with one to many relationship. 2nd table is joined to 3rd table with one to many relationship. I am using java, JPA. I have to return JSON via rest api in following format:

```
{
  "table1_id": 1,
  "somedata": "somedata",
  "table2_data": [
    {
      "table2_id": 1,
      "somedata": "somedata",
      "table3_data": [
        {
          "table3_id": 1,
          "somedata": "somedata"
        },
        {
          "table3_id": 2,
          "somedata": "somedata"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "table2_id": 2,
      "somedata": "somedata",
      "table3_data": [
        {
          "table3_id": 3,
          "somedata": "somedata"
        },
        {
          "table3_id": 4,
          "somedata": "somedata"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I use mysql and above table structure I will need to use minimum 3 database calls to fetch from 3 tables separately and will have to construct my json. Is there a way where I can reduce database calls and also reduce effort to construct my json? I am open to change database(mysql) also. I just need fast, optimised and best solution. Note that table1, table2 and table3 has different fields so I can not denormalize them to single table.

I already have seen this question and my question is different than this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047151/nested-json-from-3-one-to-many-tables

Comment: Which are the primary keys of your tables? And the foreigh keys?

Comment: id field from each table is primary key of that table. Table1_id and Table2_id are the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
    row_to_json (r1.*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            table_1_id, 
            somedata,
            array(
                SELECT
                    row_to_json (r2.*)
                FROM
                (
                SELECT 
                        table_2_id, 
                        somedata,
                        array(
                            SELECT
                                row_to_json(r3.*, true)
                            FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    table_3.table_3_id,
                                    table_3.somedata
                                FROM
                                    table_3
                                WHERE
                                    table_3.table_2_id = table_2.table_2_id
                                ORDER BY
                                    table_3_id
                            ) r3

                        ) AS table_2_data
                  FROM 
                        table_2  
                 WHERE 
                        table_2.table_1_id = table_1.table_1_id 
                 ORDER BY 
                        table_2_id
                ) r2
           ) AS table_2_data
        FROM 
            table_1
    ) AS r1
```

(with a few caveats, because your first level response is not an array; and I think it should).

The syntax is a bit convoluted and can probably be simplified

Test it at http://rextester.com/SEZ32413

Comment: Thanks joanolo. I will try this solution and will update here.

Comment: Thanks joanolo. It is giving me expected result in single database call. But this query contains many nested queries. Will it be efficient solution ?

Comment: You need to check three tables... no matter what.